# Is there a good WPF diagrammer / toolkit / provider?

Tags: .net, wpf, diagram

Basically we need a custom diagram component in our new WPF based application.
**Needs** to show text/lines, linked 2D Nodes and custom images apart from the other diagramming features like Undo/Redo, Align, Group, etc.. ala Visio.

The initial team did a bit of investigation and settled on the WinForms Northwoods GoDiagrams suite... a solution to embed it in our WPF application. 
Are there any equivalent WPF diagramming packages out there yet? Preferably tried ones.
Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

My colleague has been using [WpfDiagram](http://www.mindfusion.org/wpfdiagram.html) from MindFusion for the last two weeks and says that it's an excellent product.

Answer (score 3):

Mindscape provide a WPF Flow Diagram component which includes a base library that exposes nodes, connections, etc. Includes grouping, undo/redo and the features you mention.

Not free, but there is a trial to see if it meets your needs.

[Mindscape WPF Flow Diagrams](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/wpfflowdiagrams/)

Comment: Mindscape and MindFusion are two different companies, I first got confused by the names.

Answer (score 1):

What about [WPF Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) - this one is free. Is there someone with any experience with this?

Comment: We did use it in XCase (http://xcase.codeplex.com/) and it does not scale well. The tool gets laggy when there is a lot of nodes and lines on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember DO NOT choose Syncfusion.

I've been suffering from it when developing WPF Application. There are so many bugs in it.